# Real-time div post filter

Tags: wordpress, html, filter, posts

I am having a hard time finding an answer to this. How can I make a real-time post filter for a wordpress posts displaying `div`?
Like so

[image]

I want the blog to have a div that displays the posts, and the user to scroll for them, but to be a filter sort of search bar on top of it. So it's like a list filter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you comfortable using jQuery?  I've done something similar starting with a normal `<select>` box, then using the [`select2`](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2) jQuery library to transform it.  The library has plenty of examples on [its documentation page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Comment: So sorry I meant a posts displaying div, not a box. You see.. I want the blog to have a div that displays the posts, and the user to scroll for them, but to be a filter sort of search bar on top of it.
edit: so it's like a list filter you know

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/noth1ng/ytYQd/ (from [this thread](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-filter-a-list-based-on-an-entry-in-a-text-box))?